# Add key-value pair in every array element in multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible without using **foreach** to add key-value to the every array element?
I need to add at the end of all arrays **type => image**.
I have array like this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["idfile"]=>
    string(2) "71"
    ["iduser"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(60) "11745552_873843849371628_3215645663726390853_n-57335133dee48"
    ["extension"]=>
    string(3) "jpg"
    ["isImage"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_deleted"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["add_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-05-11 15:35:15"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["idfile"]=>
    string(2) "72"
    ["iduser"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "black-57335133e1ded"
    ["extension"]=>
    string(3) "jpg"
    ["isImage"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_deleted"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["add_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-05-11 15:35:15"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["idfile"]=>
    string(2) "73"
    ["iduser"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(21) "Canon_1-57335133e4394"
    ["extension"]=>
    string(3) "jpg"
    ["isImage"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_deleted"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["add_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-05-11 15:35:15"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you edit and show what you want to be the result array. also you are saying without foreach - is this exclude for loop as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_walk()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and define the first argument of your callback as reference, but I assume foreach is a bit faster.

```
array_walk($array, function (&$value) {
    $value['type'] = 'image';
});
```

Comment: what is the reaaon to avoid foreach?